# JSF 2.0 Accessing Application Scope bean from another Bean

Tags: jsf-2

I am using jsf 2.0 and I have two bean Navigation (Application Scope ) and Module (Request Scope). I want to use methods of Navigation bean in Module Bean. I am doing in this way 
In Module Bean

```
 @ManagedProperty(value = "#{navigationBean}")
    private NavigationBean navigationBean;
```

But  when I am trying to get `navigationBean.SomeMethod` it is not working as  navigation bean is null . How to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The both beans needs to be a fullworthy `@ManagedBean`. The acceptor should have a public setter method for the injected bean. The injected bean is only available in `@PostConstruct` and beyond (i.e. in all normal event methods, but thus **not** in the constructor of the acceptor).

So, this ought to work:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Navigation {
    // ...
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Module {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{navigation}")
    private Navigation navigation;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        navigation.doSomething();
    }

    public void setNavigation(Navigation navigation) {
        this.navigation = navigation;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `@ManagedProperty` requires a public set method to work.

Answer (score 1):

I got The solution

I have  a method in  application  signature   boolean getReadAccess(String role, String module ). If i want to use in another bean then i have to follow these steps

```
    `javax.el.MethodExpression readAccess;
     javax.el.ELContext elContext = null;
     javax.faces.context.FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     elContext = ((FacesContext) context).getELContext();
     javax.faces.application.Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
     javax.el.ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();
     readAccess = expressionFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext,
            "#{navigationBean.getReadAccess}", Void.class, new Class[] {
                    String.class, String.class });

    //--------Call----------------------------
    return (Boolean) readAccess.invoke(elContext, new Object[] {
                "roleName", "moduleName" });
```

`