# JSF howto link Beans

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee

Don't be to hard on me, this is my first try with JSF.

I have a `ManagedBean` with `ApplicationScope` which shall hold some information for all visitors. Now it should be able to change the information in this bean, but I want that done from some other bean.

How can I link my beans? Is there some `autowire` annotation or how do you build a datastructure with more than one bean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094668/jsf-2-0-accessing-application-scope-bean-from-another-bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JSF2 you can inject one bean into another bean.

Inside `faces-config.xml` use the following to inject `visitorBean` to `appScopeBean`.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>appScopeBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.app.AppScopeBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>visitorBean</property-name>
        <value>visitorBean</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Don't forget to add visitorBean field (with getters and setters) inside AppScopeBean.

Comment: That's the old JSF 1.x way. The JSF 2.x way is much easier. See also the duplicate question link.